# problem occuring while creating .exe file

Tags: bash, scripts, sudo, compiling

I'm trying to run test problem in the `mfix` but got struck with an error `sh: 0: Can't open ../../model/make_mfix`.

```
bhaskar@admin2-Precision-T7600:~/mfix/run/tests/Added_Mass$ sh ../../model/make_mfix
sh: 0: Can't open ../../model/make_mfix
```

can anyone tell why it occurs and how to get rid of it.

Comment: It seems that ../../model/make_mf doesn't exists. Check file name and path.

Answer (score -1):

Does the file exist and do you have read permissions on it. Is it executable, it's directory path needs to be executable. The commands ls -l and chmod will help.
Secondly your terminology is a bit microsoft, sh files which execute more like  .bat files and binaries which ms calls  .exe.